# Java 11 Lambda - check each object, return true when the first condition is met, else return false

Tags: java, lambda, java-11

I have a method that works fine. This is how it looks.

```
private boolean roomWithMoreThanTenFurnitures(Building building) {
if (building != null && building.hasRooms()) {
    for (Room room : building.getRooms()) {
        if (room.getFurnitures.size() > 10) {
            return true;
        }
    }   
}
return false;
}
```

I wanna switch this to Lambda. In came uo with the shell, but I am not sure how fill in the if (condition) return true or return false outside.

```
building.getRooms().forEach(room -> {
//??
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this. Returns `false` based on the initial conditions, then streams the  rooms.  This presumes the rooms can be streamed (e.g a List). If they are an array you will need to do something similar to `Arrays.stream(building.getRooms())`

```
private boolean roomWithMoreThanTenFurnitures(Building building) {
    if (building != null && building.hasRooms()) {
        return building.getRooms().stream()
                .anyMatch(room -> room.getFurnitures.size() > 10);
                
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Or just `return building != null && building.hasRooms() && building.getRooms().stream() .anyMatch(room -> room.getFurnitures.size() > 10);`

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do it this way - the `foreach` is for executing some action for every of the collection/stream element not for filtering them or mapping to a result

You need e.g. `anyMatch` method - for example

```
building.getRooms().stream().anyMatch(room -> room.getFurnitures.size() > 10)
```